# TCPDF: changing font size in the header

Tags: tcpdf

Is it possible to change the font size of characters in the header? All font settings I've tried only seem to affect the body of the PDF file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using the default headers, call this before you call the AddPage method.

```
$pdf->setHeaderFont(array('fontnamehere', 'stylehere', fontsize));
```

For example, here's one I used with my own project:

```
$pdf->setHeaderFont(array('playtime', '', 20));
```

Which set the header to use the regular-styled playtime font (a font I added to my installation) at 20pt.  I assume it's points anyway. The array isn't documented anywhere I could find, which is typical of TCPDF documentation.  I should note that larger sizes may not fit like you expect, so you can set the content container's top margin to allow more space for a different sized header, like this:

```
$topheader = 40; //Just an example, new top margin in current TCPDF units.
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, $topheader, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
```

And I'd like to take a moment again to stress that it should be called before AddPage is called, I learned a hard lesson regarding that myself.

If you want to do more complex headers, you can also write your own `Header` and `Footer` methods by extending the class, as in example 3 on the TCPDF site.

Comment: Are you aware of any change? That method does not affect the font in my headers...

Comment: According to the docs this should still work the same way.  I'll do some tests later with newer versions.  In the mean time make absolutely certain that you're calling `setHeaderFont` before the first page is added.